# FreeRtos problems in ADC task and Streaming Task

Tags: c, freertos

I have an ADC task that uses 4 channels and uses the DMA for transfer.
I also have a streaming client which streams the ADC data through the TCP socket.
I made the ADS Task lower priority than the streaming client.

I'm sending an integer that selects which ADC channel is selected as a message queue to the streaming client.

The problem is I get queue overflow when sending that adc channel integer.

**ADC TASK**

```
  if(bufferSelect != BUFFERS_NOT_READY)
        {
            if(xQueueSend(g_adcQueue, &bufferSelect,  0) != pdPASS)
            {
                throwError(ERROR_MESSAGE_QUEUE_FULL);
                PRINTF("%s\r\n", getErrorMessage(ERROR_MESSAGE_QUEUE_FULL));
            }
            bufferSelect = BUFFERS_NOT_READY;
        }
```

**Streaming client task**

```
/* obtain next buffer ready event */
        if(xQueueReceive(g_adcQueue, &bufferSelect, 0) == pdFALSE)
        {
            g_stopStreaming = true;
            continue;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that every task is blocking at one point or another to give time to the other tasks? Is the streaming client task being executed at all?

Comment: yes both tasks executed, but the queue buffer is overflowed

Comment: Then it simply means that the consumer task is not executed often enough. How often the produces puts items into the queue? How often the consumer takes them out from the queue?

Comment: The produces gets the ADC from DMA sampeled at 125khz, the consumer is a streaming client, that just gets an integer from the producer. I don't know how much tasks are executed in FreeRtos

Comment: If you don't know how often your tasks are being executed then your already are in trouble (how do you know that you have spare CPU time?). Trace your system with a tool like SEGGER SystemView or at least save the tick count at the beginning of the task loop in the suspected task to an array and see.